# gsutil rsync not preserving uid/gid ownership

Tags: google-cloud-storage

when using gsutil -m rsync -p -d -r

the ownership became root

Any idea how to run gsutil rsync just like rsync -a?

thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1):

`gsutil rsync` doesn't currently support preserving POSIX file attributes in the cloud.

It's not guaranteed that the uid/gid on the system that uploaded a file is even valid on the system that downloaded the file.  So (at least for now), you'll need to manage your file permissions manually.

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil rsync` and `gsutil cp` now both support the `-P` parameter to preserve posix attributes. From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync):

> -P
>
> Causes POSIX attributes to be preserved when objects are copied. With this feature enabled, gsutil rsync will copy fields provided by stat. These are the user ID of the owner, the group ID of the owning group, the mode (permissions) of the file, and the access/modification timestamps of the file. For downloads, these attributes will only be set if the source objects were uploaded with this flag enabled.
>
> On Windows, this flag will only set and restore access time and modification time. This is because Windows doesn't have a notion of POSIX uid/gid/mode.

One caveat worth mentioning that is not present in the docs is that this only preserves attributes for /files/, since GCS doesn't technically store the directories, thus if you are restoring a directory tree the owner and mode of the directories will not be preserved.

Also for completeness worth mentioning that the storage needed for custom metadata (which is where they store the posix attributes) is charged in addition to the storage of the file, so this will add ~150B per file stored.